# C++11 forward_list iterator remains pointing to removed value

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, forward-list

An iterator remains to point to the element it previously did and the value it points to is not removed from memory. I wonder how can this be explained? Thank you.

```
forward_list<int> Fwdl {46, 21, 88, 901, 404};
auto it = Fwdl.begin();

Fwdl.remove(46);

cout << "List : "; for(int& elem : Fwdl) cout << " " << elem; cout << endl;

//This prints "List : 21 88 901 404" as expected, but:

cout << "Iterator is alive! " << *it << endl;

//This still prints "Iterator is alive! 46"
```

Comment: "value it points to is not removed".  What does "removed" mean to you?  How do you know if a value is "removed"?

Comment: @DrewDormann i understand "removed" as removed from memory. Because tutorials describe removal as a destructive operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N4431 - 23.3.5.5/15 list operations [list.ops]** (emphasize mine)

```
void remove(const T& value);
template <class Predicate> void remove_if(Predicate pred);
```

> Effects: Erases all the elements in the list referred by a list iterator `i` for which the following conditions hold: `*i == value, pred(*i) != false`. **Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements**.

What you have is a typical manifestation of undefined behaviour and you should not rely on such code.

What probably happens is something similar to this:

```
int* p = new int(42);
int* iterator = p;
delete p;

// may still display 42, since the memory may have not yet been reclaimed by the OS, 
// but it is Undefined Behaviour
std::cout << *iterator;
```

Comment: The only way to make sure the pointer is sane is to point it to `nullptr` after any `delete` or `remove`?

Comment: This is indeed a way, but the C++ standard does not mandate this. It takes time and in C++ you don't pay for what you don't (truly) need. Moreover, iterators are decoupled from the containers, so the container *does not know* about the iterators that are pointing to its data, so when you call `remove` the container doesn't care about the invalidated iterators, and won't mark them as invalid. It is the programmers job to make sure he/she doesn't use such iterators.

Answer (score 2):

As said in one of the comments, it is undefined behavior to dereference an invalidated iterator. In your case it was probably still pointing to the space on the heap where the element used to be, and hasn't been overwritten by something else yet. On a different compiler, or a different run of the program it could have been jibbersish or crashed the program entirely.